# classList and scroll event

Tags: javascript, events, dom, scroll

I have some simple script to adding classes to my navbar relied on `pageYOffset`:

```
  var navContainer = document.querySelector('.nav-container');
  var firstTitle = document.querySelector('.first-title')
  document.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
      if(window.pageYOffset < 75){
          navContainer.classList.remove('nav-action','yellow');
      }else if(window.pageYOffset > 75){
          navContainer.classList.add('nav-action')
      }else if(window.pageYOffset<firstTitle.offsetTop){
          navContainer.classList.remove('yellow');
      }
      else if(window.pageYOffset > firstTitle.offsetTop){
          navContainer.classList.add('yellow');
      };  
    });
```

my trouble is this that last condition is fulfilled when `window.pageYOffset` is bigger than `firstTitle.offsetTop`, writing this line between brackets in the console returns true, but nothing happens when I'm trying this all code.

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: no because I`m trying to learn vanilia

Comment: Ah, okay. Alright.

Answer (score 1):

Unless `window.pageYOffset === 75`, none of these lines will actually be executed. The previous conditions already catch all the cases.

I would suggest treating `nav-action` and `yellow` separately:

```
var navContainer = document.querySelector('.nav-container');
var firstTitle = document.querySelector('.first-title')
document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (window.pageYOffset < 75) {
        navContainer.classList.remove('nav-action');
    } else {
        navContainer.classList.add('nav-action')
    }

    if (window.pageYOffset < firstTitle.offsetTop) {
        navContainer.classList.remove('yellow');
    } else {
        navContainer.classList.add('yellow');
    }
});
```